# In the .NET framework, why are there PointF (float) and no "PointD" (double)?

Tags: .net, graphics, floating-point, double, system.drawing

Can anyone explain why, in the .NET framework, there are `PointF` structures (using the single-precision `float` type) and no "PointD" (using the double-precision `double` type)?

Did they establish that such precision would never make sense in the System.Drawing namespace? Is there any other reason?

Comment: I guess a maybe upcoming migration to double precision in drawing would not legitimate twice the consumption of storage space at the time of writing this decently guessed explanation. :-) But I understand what you mean. In the maybe not so far future we might need double precision, as we now have 8 GB of RAM, thousands of GBs of HDD space 64bit CPUs and so on... and will never have more than petabytes, will we? ;-)

Comment: Which would be more useful: adding graphical point types with Double X and Y, or allowing implicit conversions from Double to Float?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

At the time when GDI+ (the technology which `System.Drawing` is based on) was developed, hardware was nowhere near the performance and capability of today, and a `Double`-based coordinate system would have imposed a heavy burden on the hardware for very little benefit on the display-end, with displays having the size and resolution that they did. Even with today's monster video cards, we are only this year seeing the ability to do double-precision floating point operations that have acceptable performance, and these are still 1/2 the speed of single-precision ops. So it was a choice of practicality to use `Single` types to model the graphics operations.

Today, with WPF, we have a platform which began with an eye toward the next decade or two, and so using `Double` to model the coordinate system made sense.

Comment: I really enjoy the explanation you gave in this answer.
Past, Present and future, Covered!